# How to Create a Trigger MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

we are having a problem with the created_at on a WordPress system. Somehow some users get that field updated "randomly" to an invalid value, so it get's set as '00000000' datetime. We haven't found the cause on the WP code, and we are now analizing the few plugins the project has. It has a large Code and user base, so we thought it might be faster to use a MySQL trigger to catch this "random" updates.

The thing is we somehow keep on hitting a syntax error on or Trigger code, and  lame SQLer's as we are, we need help trying to figure out what it could be.

What we are tying to accomplish is:

- Detect when the user table gets updated
- Check if the created_at row has been modified
- Insert the old data into a new table we created just for this purpose (user_registration_changed_records).

We decided to check for each row just in case there is some weird behaviour going on.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `user_register_updated` BEFORE UPDATE ON `wp_t8y31tcd9u_users`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF OLD.created_at != NEW.created_at

INSERT INTO user_registration_change_records (user_id, created_at) VALUES (OLD.ID, OLD.created_at) 
END IF;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

**Syntax Error**

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO user_registration_change_records (user_id, created_at) VALUES (OLD.I' at line 6

Comment: Is the syntax error confidential?

Comment: I'm sorry @Shadow it's just that I found it obscure, here it is  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO user_registration_change_records (user_id, created_at) VALUES (OLD.I' at line 6

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of syntax errors:

- missing `then` keyword before the `insert` (this is the one the error message relates to)
- missing `;` after the insert's row
- extra `;` after the `end`

At least these are the ones I can see.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `user_register_updated` BEFORE UPDATE ON `wp_t8y31tcd9u_users`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF OLD.created_at != NEW.created_at THEN

        INSERT INTO user_registration_change_records (user_id, created_at) VALUES (OLD.ID, OLD.created_at); 
    END IF;   
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

It is worthwile using mysql manual on [compound statement syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html) because all these can be found there.

Comment: Thanks a lot @shadow, I am checking that link right now. Will try correcting our code as soon as I get to the office.